# Cypress click() failed because this element is detached from the DOM in iteration

Tags: integration-testing, cypress

I try to test my **Single Page Application** with cypress. 
The first page has multiple buttons as **anchor tags** which direct you to the second site(Angular routing). 
On the second site i have a "back" button.

So i want my test to click on a button, wait for the second site to appear, click on the back and repeat this for all remaining buttons.

This is my cypress test:

```js
describe('Select products', function () {
    before(() => {
        cy.visit('http://localhost:4200/')
    })
    it('Clicking through products', function () {
    
        // getting each anchor to click 
        cy.get('a[data-cy=submit]').each(
            ($el) => {
            
                // click to get on next site
                cy.wrap($el).click()
                
                // click to go back
                cy.contains('go back').click()
            }
        )
    })
})
```

It works fine for the first run(**get all buttons => click the first => go back**) 
 but after getting back on the start site before clicking the next button cypress throws an error:

[image]

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: It seems to me that the 'go back'  has not completed before the next `.each()` iteration happens. You can ensure you are back on the first page by adding a simple test for something that is unique to the first page after `cy.contains('go back').click()`, e.g `cy.contains('h1', 'myFirstPageTitle')`.

Comment: I tried adding a ```cy.wait(3000)``` timer or a ```cy.pause()``` after the ```cy.contains('go back').click()``` but i got the same error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cy.get('a[data-cy=submit]')` must get a list of the buttons and store them to iterate via `.each()`, but the code within `.each()` navigates away from the first page - I guess that Angular destroys the original elements that `.each()` is trying to iterate over.

This is similar to iterating over a list and altering the list within the iteration, the loop fouls up because the list changes.

If you know how many buttons there are, this would be a better way

```js
const buttonCount = 4;

for (let i = 0; i < buttonCount; i++) {
  cy.get('a[data-cy=submit]').eq(i).click();
  cy.contains('go back').click();
}
```

If the buttons are dynamic (you don't know the count), use

```js
cy.get('a[data-cy=submit]').then($buttons => {

  const buttonCount = $buttons.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < buttonCount; i++) {
    cy.get('a[data-cy=submit]').eq(i).click();
    cy.contains('go back').click();
  }
}
```